# Is ‎$‎f‎$‎ ‎monotone ‎when ‎$‎f‎$ ‎is ‎concave?‎

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, monotone-functions

‎Let ‎$‎f:[1, +‎\infty‎)‎‎‎\rightarrow‎‎\mathbb{R}$ ‎be a‎ ‎concave ‎function. Suppose‎ $‎F:[1, +‎\infty‎)‎‎\rightarrow‎‎\mathbb{R}‎$ is a primitive function of ‎$‎f‎$‎. My ‎questions ‎are‎:‎

‎‎
‎(a) ‎‎What other condition is required to ‎monotone ‎‎$‎f‎$‎‎?‎

‎
‎
‎(b) Is $‎‎‎F‎$‎ concave‏?

‎‎‎‎I‎ ‎know ‎that,‎ ‎suppose $f$ is differentiable on $(a‎, ‎b)$‎. ‎Then $f$ is concave if and only if $f^\prime$ is decreasing. Also,
‎‎$‎f‎$ ‎is ‎concave, ‎then ‎‎for any ‎$‎x‎$‎￼ and ‎$‎y‎$‎ in the interval and for any ‎$‎\alpha \in [0,1]‎$‎‎‎
‎
‎‎$‎f(‎\alpha x ‎‎+ ‎(‎1 - ‎\alpha‎)y) ‎\geq ‎‎\alpha ‎f(x) +‎ ‎‎‎(‎1 - ‎\alpha‎)f(y)‎$‎.

Comment: (a) the condition is that $f$ must be monotone. (b) $F$ is concave only when $f$ is monotone.

Comment: Crostul, For (a) I want to get a condition to monotone $f$.

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a), you can use something along those lines:

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f^\prime(x) < 0$$

Having that and concavity $f^{\prime\prime}(x) < 0$, you can easily conclude that $f^\prime(x) < 0$, so f is a decreasing concave function.

There's also the symmetric case, which yields an increasing concave function:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f^\prime(x) > 0$$

Comment: Todor Markov. ‎You mean tha‏t ‎if ‎‎$‎f‎$ ‎is ‎concave ‎and ‎‎$‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}f^\prime(x)‎<0‎$, ‎then ‎‎$‎f‎$ ‎is ‎monotone.

Answer (score 2):

For (a), I don't think a simple answer exists. Concavity and monotonicity are fairly unconnected properties. You can have concave monotone, concave non-monotone, non-concave monotone or non-concave non-monotone functions.

For (b), the answer is a simple no. For example, $f(x)=-3(x-5)^2$ is a concave function, however its integral, $F(x)=-(x-5)^3$, is not a concave function.

Comment: Than you. For (b) What condition is required for concave $F$?

Comment: @koohyareslami If $f$ is decreasing, then $F$ is concave.

Comment: ‎Since ‎$‎F^\prime =‎ ‎‎f‎$ ‎and ‎$f‎$ ‎is ‎decreasing, ‎so ‎‎$‎F^\prime‎‎$ ‎is ‎decreasing. ‎Thus ‎‎$‎F‎$ ‎is ‎concave. ‎Is ‎it ‎true‏‎?‎‎

Comment: @koohyareslami Exactly.

Comment: 5xum . Thank you so much.